# Adding a fullscreen button to a Windows media player object in HTML

Tags: html, windows-media-player

Is there a way to tell a Windows Media player object to have a button for fullscreen in this HTML?

```
<div id="player" style="position: relative; top: 20px; left: 35px; width: 64.5%; border: 2px solid grey; z-index: 40;">
             <object id="MediaPlayer" width="100%" height="377" classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; z-index: 40;" type="application/x-oleobject">
                    <param name="uiMode" value="full" />
                    <param name="AutoStart" value="FALSE" />
                    <param name="AllowChangeDisplaySize" value="TRUE" />
                    <param name="AutoSize" value="TRUE" />
                    <param name="Volume" value="100" />
                    <param name="URL" value=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 />
                    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" name="MediaPlayer" src=mms://bstreamlivewm.fplive.net/bstreamlive-live/bstream2 width="100%" height="377" showcontrols="1" showtracker="1" autostart="0" volume="100" />              
            </object>                   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The video will automatically shown in fullscreen if you doubleclick the video. That is a proprietary handling by Windows Media Player. You can even disable nor enable it. The only options you have to customize the GUI of the WMP is by changing the `uiMode` to e.g. `mini`.